# Flash drive won't boot or mount after trying to create installation medium

Tags: boot, usb, mount

I have a 1GB USB flash drive which I wanted to use as an installation medium for Linux distros. My first experiment was to be installing Arch on an old laptop (old enough that if I really messed it up, it wouldn't matter). I downloaded the ISO image, and put the USB into the port; it mounted automatically. Following the instructions on Arch's installation how-to page, I ran `dd if archlinux-XXXX.iso of /dev/sdg1`. I then could not see any files on the USB (whether using `ls` or nautilus). I umounted it, then plugged it back in, and it had some files on it. I'm afraid I can't remember exactly what they were, but I'm pretty sure I saw a directory named `/boot`.

I then plugged it into the laptop, which would not boot from the flash drive. I plugged the USB back into my main computer, only to be told:

```
Unable to mount 168 MB Filesystem
Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdg1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

That command, `dmesg | tail`, gives the following:
    [338915.672127] UDF-fs: No anchor found
    [338915.672133] UDF-fs: No partition found (1)
    [338955.452708] UDF-fs: No anchor found
    [338955.452714] UDF-fs: Rescanning with blocksize 2048
    [338955.479829] UDF-fs: No anchor found
    [338955.479834] UDF-fs: No partition found (1)
    [338955.527366] UDF-fs: No anchor found
    [338955.527373] UDF-fs: Rescanning with blocksize 2048
    [338955.555208] UDF-fs: No anchor found
    [338955.555213] UDF-fs: No partition found (1)

So I'm curious about what has happened here. Did I do something wrong somewhere? Why is the error message referring to a 168 MB device, when it's supposed to be 1 GB? Also, is there any way to salvage the flash drive, or is it toast?

Edit: Information from `fdisk /dev/sdg`
    Command (m for help): p [print the partition table]

```
Disk /dev/sdg: 1021 MB, 1021125120 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 973 cylinders, total 1994385 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe797d5bb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1   *           0      327679      163840   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were working from [Official Arch Linux Install Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Arch_Linux_Install_Guide#Preparing_the_Installation_Media), note that it says:

> Make sure to use /dev/sdX and not /dev/sdX1

Assuming you did `dd` to `/dev/sdg1` (as opposed to mistyping the command in your question), you've copied the ISO image into a partition on the flash drive. The partition is likely too small to hold the ISO, and the boot sector of `/dev/sdg` was untouched.

Probably the best thing to do is re-`dd` the image, using the correct target. Once that's done, `fdisk` will probably say you don't have a partition table. Note that in your `fdisk` output, the total device size is correct, 1021 MB. It's hard to say why the drive might have been formatted with a 168 MB partition.

It is possible to put the ISO in a partition, as long as the partition is big enough, but that's less likely to be bootable.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. In my bash history i had both `...of=/dev/sdg` and `...of=-/dev/sdg1`. Apparently for some reason I thought the first one didn't work. I reran `dd` just now, put it in the laptop, and the Arch installer booted just fine. Mea culpa.